# Cached image (ffimageloading) with OUT OF MEMORY error on android - xamarin forms

Tags: listview, exception, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a listview with some images in a ffimageloading:CachedImage library....
but...when I am testing I am doing it repeatedly: I open the listview and press the back button on the actionbar, at a determined time, when I press the back  button I have an exception:

> 03-02 09:31:13.511 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Explicit
>   03-02 09:31:13.522 I/art     ( 2430): Clamp target GC heap from 108MB to 96MB
>   03-02 09:31:13.522 I/art     ( 2430): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10820(745KB) AllocSpace objects, 90(1956KB) LOS objects, 3% free, 92MB/96MB, paused 136us total 9.552ms
>   03-02 09:31:13.535 D/Mono    ( 2430): GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 997 num_hash_entries 50753 sccs size 25365 init 0.00ms df1 37.29ms sort 7.73ms dfs2 26.26ms setup-cb 1.58ms free-data 17.62ms links 67211/67211/24685/2 dfs passes 118961/92576
>   03-02 09:31:13.535 D/Mono    ( 2430): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 79.60ms
>   03-02 09:31:13.535 D/Mono    ( 2430): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 9136K in use: 8634K
>   03-02 09:31:13.535 D/Mono    ( 2430): GC_MAJOR: (LOS overflow) time 60.53ms, stw 67.10ms los size: 27648K in use: 8339K
>   03-02 09:31:13.578 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>   03-02 09:31:13.578 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>   03-02 09:31:13.580 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>   03-02 09:31:13.585 I/art     ( 2430): Clamp target GC heap from 108MB to 96MB
>   03-02 09:31:13.585 I/art     ( 2430): Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4847(397KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 92MB/96MB, paused 191us total 5.177ms
>   03-02 09:31:13.585 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>   03-02 09:31:13.594 I/art     ( 2430): Clamp target GC heap from 108MB to 96MB
>   03-02 09:31:13.594 I/art     ( 2430): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 92MB/96MB, paused 172us total 8.267ms
>   03-02 09:31:13.594 I/art     ( 2430): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 7MB allocation
>   03-02 09:31:13.594 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>   03-02 09:31:13.602 I/art     ( 2430): Clamp target GC heap from 108MB to 96MB
>   03-02 09:31:13.602 I/art     ( 2430): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 92MB/96MB, paused 178us total 7.794ms
>   03-02 09:31:13.602 W/art     ( 2430): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 8294412 byte allocation with 4161352 free bytes and 3MB until OOM"
>   03-02 09:31:13.602 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>   03-02 09:31:13.602 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>   03-02 09:31:13.604 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>   03-02 09:31:13.609 I/art     ( 2430): Clamp target GC heap from 108MB to 96MB
>   03-02 09:31:13.609 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>   03-02 09:31:13.613 I/art     ( 2430): Clamp target GC heap from 108MB to 96MB
>   03-02 09:31:13.614 I/art     ( 2430): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 7MB allocation
>   03-02 09:31:13.614 I/art     ( 2430): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>   03-02 09:31:13.621 I/art     ( 2430): Clamp target GC heap from 108MB to 96MB
>   03-02 09:31:13.621 I/art     ( 2430): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 92MB/96MB, paused 186us total 7.048ms
>   03-02 09:31:13.621 W/art     ( 2430): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 8294412 byte allocation with 4162792 free bytes and 3MB until OOM"
>   03-02 09:31:13.621 D/skia    ( 2430): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
>   Unhandled Exception:
>   Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 8294412 byte allocation with 4162792 free bytes and 3MB until OOM

before this error I also can see in output:

> 03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.MiniLoggerWrapper.Error (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\MiniLoggerWrapper.cs:30 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.MiniLoggerWrapper.Error (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\MiniLoggerWrapper.cs:30 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.MiniLoggerWrapper.Error (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\MiniLoggerWrapper.cs:30 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.MiniLoggerWrapper.Error (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\MiniLoggerWrapper.cs:30 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.MiniLoggerWrapper.Error (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\MiniLoggerWrapper.cs:30 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.MiniLoggerWrapper.Error (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\MiniLoggerWrapper.cs:30 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.MiniLoggerWrapper.Error (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\MiniLoggerWrapper.cs:30 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.MiniLoggerWrapper.Error (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\MiniLoggerWrapper.cs:30 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.MiniLoggerWrapper.Error (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\MiniLoggerWrapper.cs:30 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.MiniLoggerWrapper.Error (System.String errorMessage, System.Exception ex) [0x00000] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Helpers\MiniLoggerWrapper.cs:30 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   at FFImageLoading.Work.WorkScheduler+d__43.MoveNext () [0x001bb] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Work\WorkScheduler.cs:158 
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError stack trace ---
>   03-02 09:28:17.208 I/mono-stdout( 2430): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
>   03-02 09:28:17.211 I/Choreographer( 2430): Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I updated the ffimageloading but the error still here...I tried the

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=old
```

in a enviroment txt

This is my xaml in PCL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.ProdutosView"          
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.LayoutScripts"
         xmlns:interface="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.Interface"
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         BackgroundImage="prodBackground.jpg"
         x:Name="ParentHost">

<ContentPage.Content>

        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9.4*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Lista de produtos -->
            <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="listview_produtos" Margin="10,0,10,0" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <ListView.Header>

                <!-- Observação -->
                <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="prod_stack_obser" IsVisible="False" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label x:Name="label_observ" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Margin="20,10,0,10" />
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="lapis" Source="lapis.png" IsVisible="False" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="20"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                        <Grid Margin="20,0,20,20">
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="texturaCateg.png" BackgroundColor="{Binding FundoColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="produtos_stack_color" Spacing="10">

                                <StackLayout Spacing="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,10,10,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage FadeAnimationForCachedImages="True" DownsampleUseDipUnits="True" DownsampleHeight="60" HeightRequest="83" WidthRequest="130" Source="{Binding imagem}" Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                                            <!--<ffimageloading:CachedImage.CacheKeyFactory>
                                                <interface:CustomCacheKeyFactory/>
                                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage.CacheKeyFactory>-->
                                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                                        <!--HeightRequest="83" WidthRequest="100"-->
                                        <!--DownsampleHeight="83"-->
                                        <!--<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                                <Label Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Text="R$" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                                <Label Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Text="{Binding valor}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="30"/>
                                            </StackLayout>-->

                                </StackLayout>

                                        <!--nome-->
                                    <Label Text="{Binding nome}"  Margin="0,10,0,10" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

                                </StackLayout>
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding observacao}" Opacity="1" FontSize="Small" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.Footer>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Grid x:Name="prod_rl_fundo" >
                    <Grid.Margin>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                                 iOS="20,0,20,0"
                                 Android="20,10,20,10"/>
                    </Grid.Margin>
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="prod_acomp_img" Source="texturaCateg.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                        <!--Acompanhamentos-->
                    <StackLayout x:Name="stack_acompanhamentos" Spacing="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

                        <Grid x:Name="prod_acompanhamentos_title" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.2"/>
                            <Label x:Name="produtos_acomp_title" Text="+ Dois Acompanhamentos" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Margin="20,20,20,20" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                        </Grid>

                    </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>

                <BoxView HeightRequest="50"></BoxView>
                </StackLayout>

            </ListView.Footer>

            </ListView>

            <!--Rodapé Grid-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="rodape.png" 
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Grid.Row="0"/>

            <!--Escrito Rodapé-->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                   Margin ="5,5,5,5" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Label
                   FontSize="Micro"
                   Text="Você está em:"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="White"/>

                    <Label FontSize="Micro"
                   Text="loja"
                   x:Name="prod_lbl_lojaprox"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource laranjacolor}"
                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

My mainActivity:

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        //inicializa imageCircle
        ImageCircleRenderer.Init();

        //shared Preferences
        App.Init(new AndroidUserPreferences());

        //Gerenciador de memória
        CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
        var config = new FFImageLoading.Config.Configuration()
        {
            VerboseLogging = false,
            VerbosePerformanceLogging = false,
            VerboseMemoryCacheLogging = false,
            VerboseLoadingCancelledLogging = false,
            FadeAnimationForCachedImages = false,
            MaxMemoryCacheSize = 50000000,
            FadeAnimationDuration = 500

            //Logger = new CustomLogger(),
        };
        FFImageLoading.ImageService.Instance.Initialize(config);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

     public override void OnTrimMemory([GeneratedEnum] TrimMemory level)
    {
        FFImageLoading.ImageService.Instance.InvalidateMemoryCache();
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

        base.OnTrimMemory(level);
    }

    public override void OnLowMemory()
    {
        FFImageLoading.ImageService.Instance.InvalidateMemoryCache();
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

        base.OnLowMemory();
    }
```

My images are base64 (png)
they have 8kb and they are 150x84 px

one of them :

> data:image/png;base64,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

update: I have Searched so much...Do I need a cache key??

Comment: Any help is welcome!!

Comment: Do you ever clean up the CachedImages when you leave the view?

Comment: with the line "invalidate cache"?

Comment: The creator of this library said "FFImageLoading manages memory usage automatically, you shouldn't worry about anything in most scenarios. If you exceed MaxMemoryCacheSize (configurable), it automatically removes bitmaps that are least used from memory, the rest is managed by OS. You shouldn't worry about memory usage until loading some huge amounts of images or some big size images."...in my case it doesn't seem be this way...

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented InvalidateMemoryCache into MainActivity? Read more at https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Advanced-Usage#clear-cache-and-memory-considerations

```
    public override void OnTrimMemory([GeneratedEnum] TrimMemory level)
    {
        FFImageLoading.ImageService.Instance.InvalidateMemoryCache();
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

        base.OnTrimMemory(level);
    }

    public override void OnLowMemory()
    {
        FFImageLoading.ImageService.Instance.InvalidateMemoryCache();
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

        base.OnLowMemory();
    }
```

I think, the problem is with your base64 logic, but lets try this.

Comment: I will try it now!

Comment: It didn't work
I Setted a breakpoint in the onlowmemory, it's never called.